# update signature from file by lotusscript

Tags: lotusscript

I'm new in lotusscript and I want to update signature rich text from html file every time when i can acces the file. So when I will change html file automatic it will change signature.
I have tryed in onload form event below code but not luck. I use Domino Designer 8.5

```
Sub Onload(Source As Notesuidocument)
'*********************************************************
'Refresh Signature from html file and if file is aviable
'*********************************************************
If source.IsNewDoc Then 
    Dim session As New NotesSession

    'Open users mail database
    Set dbMail = session.CurrentDatabase

    If Not dbMail.IsOpen Then
        Call dbMail.OpenMail
    End If

    Set docProfile = dbMail.GetProfileDocument("CalendarProfile")

    'Check if file exist
    If Not Dir$( "mypath\fileName.html", 0 ) = "" Then

        Set workspace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")
        Call workspace.EditDocument(True, Source)
        Set curDoc =  source.Document

        Dim tmpRich As New NotesRichTextItem( curDoc , "Signature_Rich" )

        Call source.GotoField("Signature_Rich")
        Call source.Import("HTML File", "mypath\fileName.html") '// seems that Import does not exist.
        Set newRich= curDoc.GetFirstItem("Signature_Rich")

        Dim richTextItem As New NotesRichTextItem( docProfile , "Signature_Rich" )
        Call richTextItem.AppendRTItem (newRich)
        'Call richTextItem.AppendText ("test")
        Call docProfile.Save(True, False) 
    End If
End If End Sub
```

Comment: Where did you put this code? The "Onload"- Event of which form? Onload event usually happens to early, and with the "Call workspace.EditDocument(True, Source)" you change the current document window (and I am not sure, if this works in onLoad)... And: This code mixes NotesUIDocument and NotesDocument and can never run properly.

Comment: I ran it in Message Form. I mix NotesUIDocument with NotesDocument because I could not find any solution to update rich signature from file

Comment: I have try to load signature in CalendarProfile form using NotesUIDocument but after closing the form it does not keep any change

Comment: Changing a richtext field while the doc is open isn't a good idea.

Comment: OK, then tell me then the good one, because all bad ideas I had try

Answer (score 0):

Since the assumption is that the HTML file is the authoritative source for the signature, why even both with importing it? Just configure the calendar profile to use the HTML file.  If you need to do that programmatically to prevent users from changing the signature, then you can use this code to ensure that the calendar profile is configured properly. You can put this in the Message form’s QueryOpen. You probably also want to do this for the Reply and Reply With History & Attachment forms as well.

```
If source.IsNewDoc Then
    Dim s As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Set db = s.CurrentDatabase

    Dim profile As NotesDocument
    Set profile = db.GetProfileDocument("CalendarProfile")    

    Call profile.ReplaceItemValue("SignatureOption", "2")
    Call profile.ReplaceItemValue("Signature_2", "mypath\fileName.html")
    Call profile.Save(True, False)
End If
```

There are better tools out there for managing signatures and I would highly recommend using those instead of this method.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is nice solution, but the problem is that html file is locate on local network server, so some times I don't have access to file. With your configuration when you don't have access to file you will get en error and mail without signature. Actualy is possible to get file from etc. nfs server?